# VS2012 C# WPF MessageBox quick typing method error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, messagebox

I'm writing a program in Visual Studio 2012 C# using WPF where I like to use MessageBoxes for some quick debugging and would usually type

*mb [tab][tab]*

To get the following message box code to appear

```
global::System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Test");
```

However, I get the error message

*The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*

The code

```
global::System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Test");
```

Works perfectly though I'm getting sick and tired of having to remove *.Forms* every time I make a message box.

Is there anyway to change the

*mb [tab][tab]*

Behaviour to output

```
global::System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Test");
```

instead of

```
global::System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Test");
```

?

It's very painful

Also, what is the term for these (*mb [tab][tab]*) types of shortcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's **code snippet**. Why not create your own [code snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165393%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

**Step 1:** Copy this code to a new file and save it with `.snippet` extension.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
        <Title>wpfmbox</Title>
        <Shortcut>wpfmb</Shortcut>
        <Description>Code snippet for MessageBox.Show</Description>
        <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
        <SnippetTypes>
            <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
        </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
        <Declarations>
            <Literal>
                <ID>string</ID>
                <ToolTip>String to display</ToolTip>
                <Default>"Test"</Default>
            </Literal>
            <Literal Editable="false">
                <ID>SystemWindowsMessageBox</ID>
                <Function>SimpleTypeName(global::System.Windows.MessageBox)</Function>
            </Literal>
        </Declarations>
        <Code Language="csharp">
    <![CDATA[$SystemWindowsMessageBox$.Show($string$);$end$]]>
        </Code>
    </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

**Step 2:** From the Tools -> Code Snippet Manager, choose `import` and find your .snippet file. Then as the location it is preferred to choose the **My Code Snippets** folder.

**Step 3:** Somewhere in your code, use `wpfmb`[tab][tab].

Comment: You should include a link or something... this is more of a comment.

Comment: @Hossein-Narimani-Rad Thanks, gave me just enough info to solve it. If you can change the `<![CDATA[$SystemWindowsFormsMessageBox$` to `<![CDATA[$SystemWindowsMessageBox$` I'll mark you as correct